# Python PUT request with difficult JSON

Tags: python, rest, python-requests, cloudera, put

I am attempting to make a PUT request with Python Requests. I've seen a few other posts, and as far as I can tell, I'm doing it right. Yet my JSON on the server does not update (despite getting a 200 ok for a response).

I'm positive the URL is correct and accepts a GET or PUT (no POST). I am able to successfully GET from the URL.

Here is the JSON returned from r.json() (after making a GET request):

```
{u'items': [{u'name': u'cm_yarn_container_usage_job_pool', u'value': u'yarn'},
            {u'name': u'cm_yarn_container_usage_job_user', u'value': u'yarn'},
            {u'name': u'cm_yarn_enable_container_usage_aggregation',
             u'value': u'true'},
            {u'name': u'hadoop_secure_web_ui', u'value': u'true'},
            {u'name': u'hdfs_service', u'value': u'hdfs'},
            {u'name': u'yarn_core_site_safety_valve',
             u'value': u'long string here'},
            {u'name': u'yarn_fs_scheduled_allocations',
             u'value': u'{"long": "unicode string here"}'},
            {u'name': u'yarn_nodemanagers_healthy_thresholds',
             u'value': u'{"warning":80,"critical":75}'},
            {u'name': u'yarn_service_cgroups', u'value': u'true'},
            {u'name': u'yarn_service_lce_always', u'value': u'true'},
            {u'name': u'zookeeper_service', u'value': u'zookeeper'}]}
```

I can extract the field that I want like so:

```
>>> x['items'][7]['value']
u'{"warning":80,"critical":75}'
```

Now I am trying to update this unicode dictionary to read: `u'{"warning":79,"critical":75}'}`

I am using the Python 2 Requests Module (Python2 is all that is allowed on the server). Here is how I am trying to update the JSON on the server:

```
url = "http://nodename:7180/api/v6/clusters/<cluster-name>/services/yarn/config"
id , password = '', ''
payload = {u'items': [{u'name': u'yarn_nodemanagers_healthy_thresholds', u'value': u'{"warning":79,"critical":75}'}]}
r = requests.put(url, json=payload, auth=(id, password))
```

Does this request look correct? I've tried numerous variations but still nothing updates the JSON on the  server. Thank you.

Comment: Side note: there's no such thing as a ``JSON object``. It's either an object or a JSON **string**. But according to the [docs](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests) it seems to be okay to pass an object to ``json=...``.

Comment: That's not JSON, it's a Python dict. `u'{"warning":80,"critical":75}'` is JSON though, i.e. it's a string.

Comment: What happens when you use `json.dumps(payload)` instead of just `payload`? I've run into problems with `requests` before when trying to have it do raw translation from dict to json.

Comment: Hmmm well the JSON returned looks like that JSON above? ... It's the output of r.json()... will make EDIT above. I'll try using json(dumps) too just in case

Comment: `r.json()` interprets the response *as JSON* and *parses* it into a Python dict/list. It then ceases to be JSON.

Comment: @deceze that's a good point

Comment: as an update... json.dumps(payload) didn't work for me either... Also trying with CURL as well. One interesting thing is that curl is showing me a 302 status code